# How to set a dynamic variable for push method?

Tags: javascript, methods, push

I am trying to push some items into different Arrays. At the moment i can do that using if statements, and if i have too many arrays? how can i use dynamic variables to push elements into the array?

Comment: And your code is where?

Comment: Can you post an example of what you are trying to do? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an *Object* which references your arrays (or as the original container you create them in).

```
var env = {               // var a = [0, 2, 4], b = [1, 3, 5],
    'foo': [0, 2, 4],     //     env = {};
    'bar': [1, 3, 5]      // env['foo'] = a;
};                        // env['bar'] = b;

function addToArr(k, x) { // `k` string key, `x` item to append
    env[k].push(x);       // push `x` into array ref `env[k]`
}

addToArr('foo', 6);       // example usage
addToArr('bar', 7);

env;                      // result
/* {
    "foo": [0, 2, 4, 6],  // === a
    "bar": [1, 3, 5, 7]   // === b
} */
```

Of course, you can use whatever logic you like for the *Object's* keys and how your *function* decides upon which to use.

Comment: I hope you can see it properly 
function insert() {
    if (selectOption.value == 'family')
    {
        family.push(txtinput.value);
    }
    else if (selectOption.value == "cars") {
        cars.push(txtinput.value);
    }
    show();
}

Comment: so you would give `env` properties _family_ and _cars_ instead of _foo_ and _bar_, and re-write `addToArr` to have `k` as `selectOption.value` and `x` as `txtinput.value`.